# How to overwrite line in file without deleting other contents

Tags: php

Sample contacts.txt file:

```
doe, john, 123
smith, jane, 456
etc
etc
etc
```

If I want to overwrite `smith, jane, 456` with `cooper, jones, 678` with `$handle = fopen("contacts.txt", "w");`

How come it removes all the lines before and after `smith, jane, 456`

Comment: Read up on the different mods from `fopen()` in the manual. Also do you want to just replace a specific line? Or are you searching for the line with the content `smith, jane, 456` and then you want to replace that line?

Comment: I'm searching for a line with the content then replacing that line.

Comment: @ush That is a rather difficult way to do it. You could use `file` to pull it in as an array and go line by line, then write it back out. You could use `file_get_contents` and str_replace the line with a new line and then use `file_put_contents`. The way you are going will also require you to handle your own file locking instead of using the LOCK_EX flag for PHP file functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fopen()` may not be the best choice, especially with `w`:

> *'w'  Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of
>   the file and **truncate the file to zero length**. If the file does not
>   exist, attempt to create it.*

For reasonably sized files this should do it:

```
$data = file_get_contents('contacts.txt');
$data = str_replace('smith, jane, 456', 'cooper, jones, 678', $data);
file_put_contents('contacts.txt', $data, LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: I'd do an exclusive lock on the write. What if two processes run this at the exact same time?

Comment: @kainaw: Good call, added.